# How to use loop in url webpage using python requests

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to extract information from the webpage, where I want to run the loop in url web pages. any help?

```
abc = f"https://www.myntra.com/flat-60-sale?f=Brand%3AArrow%2CArrow%20New%20York%2CArrow%20Sport%2CBlackberrys%2CColorPlus%2CCrocodile%2CIndian%20Terrain%2CMarks%20%26%20Spencer%2CPark%20Avenue%2CParx%2CV%20Dot%2CVan%20Heusen%2CVan%20Heusen%20Sport%3A%3ACategories%3AShirts%3A%3AGender%3Amen%2Cmen%20women%3A%3AOccasion%3AFormal%3A%3Asize_facet%3A44&p=3&sort=price_asc"
for p in range(2,5):
    d = abc.replace("&p=3", "&p={p}") 
    d1 = f"{d}"
    re = requests.get(d1)
    print(re.status_code)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using api to extract data. I have used random websites to establish the connection. Once it is done I will implement the same in my api. 
want to give url through input command

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have slightly misunderstood f-strings. `abc` should look like this:

```
abc = "https://www.myntra.com/flat-60-sale?.......&p={}&sort=price_asc"
```

You can then set the p value in your for-loop, like this:

```
for p in range(2,5):
    d1 = abc.format(p)
    re = requests.get(d1)
    print(re.status_code)
```

Rather than receiving three `404` status codes, you should get three `200` status codes now

Comment: Thanks. I got where I did mistakes. 
Thanks again